# Getting an HTML table to include rows for empty dates

Tags: php, mysql

The code below echoes out an HTML table with two columns: the first column has a date, the second column has a deal scheduled for that date.  It only shows dates in the upcoming 90 days.

Some of the dates don't have deals, and the HTML table omits those dates.  How can I include them?  I would like the "deal" column to simply be blank for unscheduled dates.

```
   $sqlStr = "SELECT c.date, d.deal, d.datescheduled
                 FROM calendar_table c
                 JOIN deals d ON d.datescheduled = c.dt
                WHERE c.dt > NOW() 
             ORDER BY c.dt ASC
             LIMIT 90"; 

    $arr = array(); 
    echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 



        echo '<tr style="border-left:0px solid #C9C9C9; border-right:0px solid #C9C9C9; border-top:0px solid #C9C9C9;" class="class3a">';


            echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.domain.com/login/deal.php?dealid='.urlencode($row["dealid"]).'">'.$row["date"].'</a>  </td>';

            echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.domain.com/login/deal.php?dealid='.urlencode($row["dealid"]).'">'.$row["deal"].'</a>  </td>';



        }



    echo '</tr>';





echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Save the date in a variable. Then when processing the next row, check if the date is the day after the date you saved. If not, write out rows for all the missing dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your query to do a left join instead of an inner join:

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT c.date, d.deal, d.datescheduled
             FROM calendar_table c
             LEFT JOIN deals d ON d.datescheduled = c.dt
            WHERE c.dt > NOW() 
         ORDER BY c.dt ASC
         LIMIT 90";
```

This makes MySQL get all the rows in calendar_table, regardless of the existence of a matching row in deals.
Then, you check for nulls in the array, and write an empty cell instead:

```
if ($row["deal"]==null)
    echo '<td></td>';
else
    echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.domain.com/login/deal.php?dealid='.urlencode($row["dealid"]).'">'.$row["deal"].'</a>  </td>';
```

Comment: Actually, all I had to do was add the word "LEFT" in front of "JOIN," and it solved the problem.  I like simple, elegant solutions like this.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not be using `mysql_*` - it's depreciated, instead use `mysqli` or `pdo`. I won't say more because that's not what this question is about, but you should look into these other options. That being said, give this a try for your current problem:

```
$cur_date = date('Y-m-d');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_* is depreciated! Use mysqli or PDO!!!

    // While this row's date is greater than $cur_date, print empty rows
    while (strtotime($row['date']) > strtotime($cur_date)) {

        echo '<tr style="border-left:0px solid #C9C9C9; border-right:0px solid #C9C9C9; border-top:0px solid #C9C9C9;" class="class3a">';

            echo '<td class="sitename1">'.$cur_date.'</td>';

            echo '<td class="sitename1">&nbsp;</td>';

        echo '</tr>';

        // $cur_day is incremented 1 day each time until it matches this row's date
        $cur_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cur_date . '+ 1 day'));

    }

    echo '<tr style="border-left:0px solid #C9C9C9; border-right:0px solid #C9C9C9; border-top:0px solid #C9C9C9;" class="class3a">';

        echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.domain.com/login/deal.php?dealid='.urlencode($row["dealid"]).'">'.$date.'</a>  </td>';

        echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.domain.com/login/deal.php?dealid='.urlencode($row["dealid"]).'">'.$row["deal"].'</a>  </td>';

    echo '</tr>';

    // $cur_day is incremented 1 day
    $cur_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['date'] . '+ 1 day'));

}
```

Essentially, for each day between now and the last deal's date, a row is printed. If there is no deal for that day, it will just be the date and an empty column.